# A-Frame animating with components

Tags: aframe

I am learning A-Frame and have come up with an issue I am trying solve. The issue is animating a radius for a sphere to create a pulsating effect ie the sphere grows and shrinks. I have created an AFRAME Component and in the animation path i have put in the code is 
animation = "property: geometry.primitive.sphere.radius; from: 0.1; to: 0.9"
But I get an error in the console
Error: Unknown geometry schema `0.1`
so I think the "0.1" is relating to the radius value. 
I also tried another way by creating a THREE.SphereBufferGeometry but i cannot figure out the components path to put into the animation property.
Can anyone advise me the best way to animate the radius of a sphere i would greatly appreciate it.
Thanks
Darren

Comment: you could add a little more of your code and put it in a code block

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "I have created an AFRAME Component" ?

To know which property to animate, you can check here on the documentation to what each property is linked. For  "radius" is associated with "geometry.radius".

I made [a glitch that shows what you want to achieve](https://glitch.com/~eggplant-bald-individual), is it what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi  thanks for the rely that is exactly what i want to do but i am still having errors i am trying to do a loop with many spheres randomly on a plane. One sphere i will animate fine but now i have a ReferenceError: "alternate is not defined" error. i would like to paste the code but it will look really messy here so i will paste it in the next reply seperately

Comment: Can you create a glitch or share a bit of your code so we can help you? It's hard to guess what's wrong without details.

Comment: so here is a link to the code https://drive.google.com/file/d/10p3cjEm7uj4brctd5zolNfXW2xXHR418/view?usp=sharing is i am basically trying to animate a sphere with a for loop by creating a AFRAME component and using the setAttribute in the init: function when i run the code o have another error ReferenceError: "alternate is not defined" so if you can help that would be great thanks

Comment: The drive file is private, I can't access it. You can use glitch to share code and see it in action live, it's pretty practical, see here : https://glitch.com/edit/#!/aframe?path=README.md%3A1%3A0

Comment: ok here is a link glitch https://glitch.com/edit/#!/pulseball?path=index.html%3A12%3A20

Comment: i have commented out the //dir: alternate, as that is the latest error i have

Comment: It was kinda messy, you should read the documentation a bit more about how to use entities, there were some weird things. I fixed it though, you can see the result directly in glitch with the show button on the top left. https://glitch.com/~solar-plastic-bathtub

Comment: Thanks so much for the help apologies for messy code as i am trying to teach my self so it is probably not the most artistic way of writing code but everyday is a learning day.